# Help to understand a sentence from a tv show

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I saw this sentence in the subtitle. However, I am unsure if it is correct grammatically.

> I dreamt I was snorting blow off of Tom Jones' ass.

[image]

Comment: Could you add what the characters were actually saying in English? Same as the text?

Comment: @user3169 It was the elder woman. Just forget the name. The name of the show is 'Mom'.

Comment: Yes, I know what show it is. I was asking what the spoken dialog (I presume in English) was.

Comment: @user3169 yes, in English. Just with both English and Chinese subtitles.

Comment: But what did she actually say?

Comment: @user3169, she did say the sentence I was asking here. *I dreamt I was snorting blow off of Tom Jones' ass.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence is grammatically correct.

As for the meaning, *to snort blow* means to inhale cocaine through ones nose. This is usually done by putting the cocaine in a line on a surface, before inhaling it through a tube-like object, like a rolled-up bill.

In this case, the character dreamt that she was using Tom Jones' ass as surface to snort the cocaine off.

Comment: Correct... maybe but it's very informal, slangy language.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *snort and blow*? I can't find the phrase *snort blow* on the web. It seems that blow in snort blow is a noun word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Very informal and "slangy" as in you wouldn't use it in a legal brief, but you would certainly use it when talking with people.

Comment: @dan You could also say _snort cocaine_, instead of _snort blow_. [It is mentioned in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocaine).

Answer (score 2):

It's correct, although I can't help but wonder how accurate the Chinese translation is.

Let's break it into parts.  The outer part is "I dreamt X".

> I dreamt [I was a butterfly].

The inner part is "I was doing X some place Y":

> I was [eating dinner] at [my friend's house]

Put together:

> I dreamt I was eating dinner at my friend's house.

Substitute "snorting blow" for "eating dinner", and "off Tom Jones' ass" for "at my friend's house" and you have the sentence from the TV program.

Vocabulary.

1. ["Snorting blow"](https://78.media.tumblr.com/36df7ce09a5da1693e0e7e544999dbea/tumblr_mzqd38QvZG1slwvgko1_500.gif) is slang for "inhaling cocaine through the nose".
2. [Tom Jones](http://www.tomjones.com/) is a relatively famous American singer, known to be popular with older women.
3. "Ass" is a common (if slightly rude) slang for *[buttocks](http://www.fitnessbites.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/lift-your-buttocks-1024x683.jpg)*

Comment: The part I am confused with is 'snorting blow' , which turn out to be a phrase. Thanks!